# How can I load a JS script on Bootstrap carousel ending?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap carousel with slides loaded via AJAX call.

The thing is after every cycle, I make new calls to updates the elements of the carousel.  So far, so good. The problem is, how can call a script once the full cycle is over?

If I have 10 slides, with interval of 5 seconds each the call should be done 5 after the slide number 10 was loaded. I have check bootstrap documentation and I guess it should be somehow using the event 'slid.bs.carousel' but don't know how to trigger it in the last slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution. It's important to note that:

a) In order to apply changes we need to wait for the transition to end. Because of that we used 'slid.bs.carousel' instead of 'slide.bs.carousel'

b)The key insight is that you can access the slide properties in data

```
  $('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function ( data ) {
  var lastSlide = $('.carousel-item').length - 1;
  if( data.to == lastSlide ) {
    $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
    console.log("PAUSE"); // Here comes your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers which have no description are marked as low quality; Kindly add a description to share what you have done

Comment: You are right. Sorry and thank you for your kind feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function ( data ) {
  var lastSlide = $('.carousel-item').length;
  if( data.to == lastSlide ) {
    //ajax
  }
});
```

Where `data.to` is the index of the next item.

Comment: Your code was in the right direction, but had some mistakes. My highlight was that you could actually access to data being the slide object. I didn't know that. The mistakes are that last slide is length - 1, and the event is 'slid.bs.carousel' which is after the transition has been made, because otherwise you can't pause the cycle. For me, it's an upvote because it got me the key elements, but not the correct solution.